# Hibernate - Removing an object reference without removing the object

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am creating the application using hibertnate and JPA. I have 2 classes namely Person and Associate. Person is pretty self-explanitory as it holds details of a person (name, last name, gender etc). Associate is a class that links 2 person objects together (person A lined with person B), kind of like a "friend" on facebook. Quite simply a person (person A) holds a list of associate, and an Associate object holds the other person (person B) to be linked and the type of relationship they have (friends, family etc). This way person A can know who he/she is associated with (i.e person A knows he is linked with person B). The structure is blow.

What is suppose to happen is that when a person gets deleted from the database all of his associations get deleted too. That is the person deleted and the links to other people. The problem is that when I use a cascade delete in the Person class it deletes the association PLUS all the person objects in the association object. i.e if person A and person B are associated (in a associate object). When person A is deleted, the associate object is deleted AS WELL as person B. The desired result is that ONLY person A AND the associate object referencing person A is deleted and NOT person B. The person B object should remain in the database as person B hasn't been deleted, just the association between the 2 people. I am not sure how to do that. Any ideas on how i can achieve the desired result? or maybe if there is a better way to do this association of 2 person objects.

---

- Structure:

---

**PERSON CLASS**

@Entity

public class Person implements Serializable {

```
 private Long id;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String gender;
 @OneToMany (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
 @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
 @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
 private List<Associate> associations;

 //setters
 //getters
```

}

**ASSOCIATE CLASS**
@Entity

public class Associate implements Serializable {

```
 private Long id;
 @ManyToOne
 private Person associate;
 private String relationshipType;
 @OneToOne (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
 @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
 private AssociateSettings;

 //setters
 //getters
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create only one entity - Person - this is the sketch of the class:

```
@Entity
public class Person{

 private Long id;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String gender;
 @OneToMany
 private List<Person> associates; 

 //setters
 //getters
}
```

Each person can be related to collection of other persons. Don't use cascade delete since you can easily erase half of your database starting with only one person deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought about doing that but I also need to keep track of other data like the kind of relationship 2 person have (friends, family colleagues etc). So within the list, each person would have a different relationship to the list holder. Do you know of a way I can do that using the structure you gave above? I currently can't see a way to do this.

Comment: Well...instead of creating a single list of "associates", create a list for each of the relationships: friends, family, cow-orkers, etc....

Comment: That could work too. Although I have figured out a solution. Rather than storing the person object in the associate class I will only store the ID of the relevant person. In other words I just changed the data type of associate (in the associate class) from Person to Long and just stored the ID of person under the associate attribute. That way I can not only cascade delete and not delete the actual person but I can also retrieve the full details of the person only when I need it. Thanks for to all for your help and input.